# seo friendly multilanguage with remove trailing slash on php apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get rid of apache's rewrite issues when i try to both removing trailing slash and seo friendly multilanguage page at the same time.

To be more clarify, I am able to use some functions of apache rewrite rules great with the codes below

```
# remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So what i achieve with the code is ;

```
example.com/status.php
```

turns to

```
example.com/status
```

that works great and with the code below i am assuming to remove trailing slash for every page ;

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

So what i achieve with the code is ;

```
example.com/status/
```

turns to

```
example.com/status
```

All is good till now however, when i try to use multilanguage it abuses for the reason it tries to remove trailing slash ;

```
RewriteRule ^([en|fr]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

so i need to achieve is ;

```
example.com/status?lang=fr
```

it should turn to below but i get 404 error;

```
example.com/fr/status
```

I've been seeking a solution good for but no luck

So basically what i need to achieve is ;

1. Remove .php extension
2. Remove trailing slash
3. use status?lang=fr should be turn to /fr/status
4. use status?lang=en should be turn to /status

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you are going to need two RewriteRules, one to match fr and one to match en. Also, right now, your regex  isn't capturing enough of the url to do what you want it to do.

Comment: i guess need to use something different like javascript or else. But i agree with you that need two or more separate rewriteRules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
# remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]

#Rewriting /status?lang=fr
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /status\?lang=([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/status? [NE,R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/status/?$ /status?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: you rock man !  It works however this is not what i exactly want. It turns to  '/en/status' but english is default so i want to see '/status' if lang is en and '/fr/status' if lang is fr. is it possible too ?

Comment: Linuxman, status is already a file on the server, so it will first point to status.php, can't we change its name to something else? forexample /en/status or sttatus?

Comment: Starkeen, honestly there are several of files on the server that i need to write same rules for every php file or is there any way to joker? contact, support index, etc...

Comment: one thing is missing that not working once i try to 'example.com/?lang=en' for default index